# In SQLAlchemy how can I filter my query to only include rows with non-empty jsonb column values?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, jsonb

I have a DB table that I am querying, simplified example looks like this:

```sql
+----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| entry_id | list_id | availability                                                                                                   |
|----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 130      | 199     | {"2021-10-20": {"value": "no_reply", "notify": false}, "2021-10-21": {"value": "no_reply", "notify": false}}   |
| 131      | 199     | {"2021-10-20": {"value": "no_reply", "notify": false}, "2021-10-21": {"value": "no_reply", "notify": false}}   |
| 132      | 199     | {}                                                                                                             |
| 129      | 199     | {"2021-10-20": {"value": "available", "notify": false}, "2021-10-21": {"value": "available", "notify": false}} |
+----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In my query I only want to include the rows where the availability column dict has keys, and filter out any empty ones (eg. entry_id 132) with the default value of "{}"

I've achieved some success with using `ListEntry.availability != '"{}"'` as a filter in my query, but it seems a bit hacky and I was wondering if there was a better way of doing it?

Comment: how familiar are you with the LIKE operator in SQL? You should be able to use that to make appropriate criteria. I still need to test this but I think it would look something like `select * from table where availability LIKE "{_%}"`. The underscore means exactly 1 character and % means 0 or many

Comment: I am familiar with it, thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant convert the right hand side of the comparison to jsonb:

```
SELECT * FROM ListEntry WHERE availability <> '{}'::jsonb
```